# Сортировка строки из чисел, написанных через пробелы

Tags: c++, массивы, алгоритм, строки, сортировка

Необходим алгоритм с использованием простейших функций с++, для того, что бы отсортировать числа, водимые пользователем. Есть идея все числа перегнать в массив, заранее преобразовав их в код ASSII, а потом его уже, отсортировав, вывести. Но это работает только с натуральными числами(до 9), а потом уже алгоритм не пригоден, так как двузначные числа раскладывает на составляющие и их уже сортирует. Ваши предложения? 
Спасибо.

Comment: Прочитайте строку и читайте из нее числа. Удобнее всего для этого, на мой взгляд, использовать [`std::istringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/istringstream/)

Comment: *"использованием простейших функций"* Можно точнее, что можно использовать, а что нет?

Comment: Не использовать такие функции, как предложили в коментарии выше. Нужно обойтись массивами, библиотекой string и циклами for. Ну и командами для ввода-вывода cin - cout

Comment: в библиотеке string есть функция stoi для преобразования в int, или тоже не подходит?

Comment: В любом случае, вы всегда можете с помощью только циклов for написать свою функцию перевода строкового представления числа в int.

Comment: Вот, об этой функции через for я и хочу узнать. Как мне её реализовать?

Comment: @Алексей, есть C-функция [atoi](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi), которая иногда выручает. По крайней мере, можно поискать, как она реализована. Если я Вас правильно понял, она делает как раз то, что Вам нужно. Либо можно использовать возможности потока *cin*, например `for (int value; cin >> value; ) { /*сохраняем в массив/вектор для сортировки*/ }`. Однако в этом случае ввод будет ограничиваться неправильным вводом (буквой) или символом *EOF* (`ctrl`+`D`)

Comment: ДА! Это то, что нужно. atoi() делает как раз нужное мне действие. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас есть строка цифр - то получить `int` очень легко. Что-то вроде

```
char * s = ....
int i = 0;
while(isdigit(*s))
{
    i = i * 10 + (*s - '0');
    s++;
}
```

Если и `isdigit` нельзя - то пишем его сами:

```
bool isdigit(char c)
{
    for(char i = '0'; i <= '9'; ++i)
        if (c == i) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

А ещё, как вариант, можно применить магию контейнеров, а не массив.
Более гибко получается... (сразу и частотность и уникальность и отсортировать по разному можно, лексикографически или по нормальному)
Как-то так выглядеть будит:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

int main() {
  std::string str;
  auto cf = [] (std::string a, std::string b) -> bool
  {
    return std::stoi(a) < std::stoi(b); 
  };

  std::map< std::string, int, decltype(cf) > M(cf); /// по числам
  ///std::map< std::string, int> M;  /// лексикографически
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
    std::cin >> str;
    M[str]++;
  }
  for(auto it = M.begin(); it != M.end(); ++it)
    for(int i = 0; i < it->second; ++i )
      std::cout << it->first << std::endl;

}
```